# get state of agreement paypal subscriptions

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk, recurring-billing

I have integrated paypal php rest api to create plan and then I have create billing agreement for this plan but the issue is payment is not deducting instantly and I want to know that how will came to know that payment is deducted from payee account.

after executing billing agreement I get object of billing agreement as response and in that object **it show that billing agreement is activated but in payee's account transaction status of agreement is pending** in response object **outstanding amount is also zero**

I want to know way to identify that amount is deducted form payee's account or not. so that I can take action accordingly.

Comment: I have found work around and used webhooks for it

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue but for this I have to use callback or we can say webhooks

One more thing was there is

Webhook never works on subdomain and ssl is also requiered .